# how to tag span in div JS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZKFB.jpg)
How to tag this span inside the div and the tables. There are many of this span elements with the same class on the website. It is on the wordpress website/woocommerce

There is a number and another span with a currency symbol and I would like to get only the number.

I would like to get the code of JS DOM with concrete numbrer

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "tag this span"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you are trying to to.
If you want to get the value of a certain span tag from the DOM then you could use a *[specific](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)* css selector to target that one element.

When there are multiple elements with similar properties or same css specificity, you should first try to *make* that one element stand out by giving it a unique id, class or data property within your content management system.
When that's not possible you could also try to find another pattern, like it might be the first or last element of some kind.

Possible methods to get the element

```js
// Gives you one element with id="yourSpecialElementId"
const element = document.getElementById('yourSpecialElementId');
// Gives you the first child of the element with data-title="Mezisouet"
const childElement = document.querySelector('[data-title="Mezisouet"]').firstChild;
// Gives you all elements, that are spans with class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount');
// Gives you the first element with the same classes
const firstElement = document.querySelector('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount');
```

And then to get the value you could access the innerText property `element.innerText`.

Does that answer your question?